# jQuery get element that has not same class on .parent().next()

Tags: jquery

I have this situation:

```
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="link">First Item</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="link">Second Item</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -1- Item</a>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -2- Item</a>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -3- Item</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="link">Fourth Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="link">First Item</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="link">Second Item</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -1- Item</a>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -2- Item</a>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -3- Item</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="link">Fourth Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
```

I want to get only this four:

```
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="link">First Item</a> <-- THIS
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="link">Second Item</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -1- Item</a>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -2- Item</a>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -3- Item</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="link">Fourth Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="link">First Item</a> <-- THIS
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="link">Second Item</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -1- Item</a>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -2- Item</a>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -3- Item</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="link">Fourth Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a> <-- THIS
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a> <-- THIS
```

I've tried to do this:

```
console.log(jQuery('.link').parent().find('.link:first'));
```

But I don't know how to exclude the ones on the .next() because the only reference I got is the class .link that can be anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method and filter out element which has only one or less `li` ancestor element with direct child as `.link` ( one is current element parent if it's within `li`).

```
jQuery('.link').filter(function() {
  return $(this).parents('li:has(>.link:first-child)').length < 2;
})
```

```js
jQuery('.link').filter(function() {
  return $(this).parents('li:has(>.link:first-child)').length < 2;
}).css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="link">First Item</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="link">Second Item</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="link">Third -1- Item</a>
            <a href="#" class="link">Third -2- Item</a>
            <a href="#" class="link">Third -3- Item</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="link">Fourth Item</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="link">First Item</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="link">Second Item</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="link">Third -1- Item</a>
            <a href="#" class="link">Third -2- Item</a>
            <a href="#" class="link">Third -3- Item</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="link">Fourth Item</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.link').not('li li .link').css('color','red');`

This will grab the `.link` classes which are not nested in **2** or more li levels.

```js
$('.link').not('li li .link').css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="link">First Item</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="link">Second Item</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -1- Item</a>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -2- Item</a>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -3- Item</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="link">Fourth Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="link">First Item</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="link">Second Item</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -1- Item</a>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -2- Item</a>
                                <a href="#" class="link">Third -3- Item</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="link">Fourth Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
```